# Searching Database Records in iPad/Android using Titanium Studio

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, sqlite, titanium

I am currently developing iPad application which involve retrieving information from webservice and then storing those information in the local database. Based on users searching criteria, I want to search the database to retrieve relevant database entries.  I am using Titanium Studio for developing this iPad application. Could someone suggest me if there is any plugin, standard process, or sample application to understand how to get this done in an optimal way.

Comment: is this android relevent question?

Comment: @user370305 , Since Titanium Studio can be used for Android application development, i thought that people who has developed applications for Android devices using Titanium studio might have answer for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these two videos from Appceelerator on using local data and remote data. There is also source code for these. These are what got me running.

Local data: http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/building-native-mobile-applications/video/26414892

Remote data: http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/building-native-mobile-applications/video/26414909

Source code and labs: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/td/TCAD+Course+Labs